# Convert a vector(x,y,z) coordinate into an integer between 0 and 32767

Tags: math, linear-algebra

Pretty simple question - can someone provide a formula that takes 3 numbers (x,y,z) and converts them into a single integer between 0 and 32767.

1,1,2 and 2,1,1 shouldn't be the same resulting value (simply adding the numbers up isn't what I want) but compressing an infinite number of x,y,z into a small range of numbers obviously will get the same values back quite often.

The formula also needs to work on large numbers like 5000,5000,1000

If you need to go between 0 and 131068 that would be fine, but it shouldn't be much more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to take each x,y,z and assign them each to a range of 5 bits in the 2^15 possible values in [0, 32767]. One way of doing this is taking each x,y,z modulo 2^5 (to compress them into the requisite 5 bits) and then set the bits of the result accordingly. The end result should look something like

```
def compress(x,y,z):
    x %= 32
    y %= 32
    z %= 32
    return x + (y<<5) + (z<<10)

print (compress(5000,5000,1000))
>>> 8456
```

Obviously this approach has colliding outputs very often (whenever x, y or z are the same modulo 32), but as you said this is pretty unavoidable.